# IPFS Integration with dapp developed using Embark Framework

Tags: ipfs, embark

This is the contract code.

```
      pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

     contract SimpleStorage {
           uint storedData;
           function set(uint x) {
                          storedData = x;
           }
           function get() constant returns (uint retVal) {
                          return storedData;
           }
    }
```

This is the javascript code used (index.js)

```
        var addToLog = function(txt) {
              $(".logs").append("<br>" + txt);
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {

              $("button.set").click(function() {
              var value = parseInt($("input.text").val(), 10);
              SimpleStorage.set(value);
              addToLog("SimpleStorage.set(" + value + ")");
       });

       $("button.get").click(function() {
              SimpleStorage.get().then(function(value) {
                 $(".value").html(value.toNumber());
             });
             addToLog("SimpleStorage.get()");
     });

   });
```

This is the code for html file(index.html)

```
              <html>
              <head>
                <title>Embark - SimpleStorage Demo</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
                <script src="js/app.js"></script>
             </head>
             <body class="container">
                 <h3>Embark - SimpleStorage Demo</h3>
                <h3> 1. Set the value in the blockchain</h3>
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                         <input type="text" class="text form-control" >
                         <input type="text" class="text form-control">
                         <button class="set btn btn-primary">Set Value</button>
                </div>

               <h3> 2. Get the current value</h3>
               <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        current value is <span class="value"></span>
                    </div>
               <button class="get btn btn-primary">Get Value</button>
               </div>

             <h3> 3. Contract Calls </h3>
             <div class="logs">
                <p>Javascript call being made: </p>
             </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

I am trying to integrate ipfs for storing 'x' in ipfs.I am using embark framework for developing the dapp.

I have installed ipfs-api using npm as follows.

```
         npm install --save ipfs-api
```

Then i have updated the above index.js with following lines

```
           var ipfsAPI = require('ipfs-api')

           // connect to ipfs daemon API server
           var ipfs = ipfsAPI('localhost', '5001', {protocol: 'http'})
```

what are the further modifications required in index.js and index.html files for storing and retrieving the value using ipfs?

Comment: @samuraj jack Please help me to develop a dapp using IPFS

Comment: can you please be more specific on what you are trying to do? why you need dapp? why you need ipfs?

Comment: @ max taldykin  I am trying to learn IPFS integration with dapp. Please do consider the case with default 'Simple Storage ' contract in 'Embark'.How can i integrate IPFS with it?

Comment: This is already better than your [previous attempt](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/11282/87), however, it's still not clear what exactly you need. I’d love to help you to improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @5chdn I have modified my question.please do help me

Comment: niksmac answer is perfect. A small note: as of 2.2.0 to upload to ipfs the new command is ```embark upload ipfs``` also setting the provider is needed: ```EmbarkJS.Storage.setProvider('ipfs',{server: 'localhost', port: '5001'})```

Comment: Oh, youre the creator of Embark :) Good work Iuri.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework#embarkjs---storage)

1. Set the provider:

   `EmbarkJS.Messages.setProvider('orbit', {server: 'localhost', port: 5001})`
2. Saving Text

   `EmbarkJS.Storage.saveText("hello world").then(function(hash) {});`
3. Retrieving Data/Text

   `EmbarkJS.Storage.get(hash).then(function(content) {});`

#### Deploying to IPFS

To deploy a dapp to IPFS, all you need to do is run a local IPFS node and then run `embark ipfs`. If you want to deploy to the livenet then after configuring you account on `config/blockchain.json` on the production environment then you can deploy to that chain by specifying the environment `embark ipfs production`.

EDIT from @iurimatias:
A small note: as of 2.2.0 to upload to ipfs the new command is `embark upload ipfs` also setting the provider is needed: `EmbarkJS.Storage.setProvider('ipfs',{server: 'localhost', port: '5001'})`